# Dynamic box-shadow not working (react)

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

I was trying to replicate [this](https://codepen.io/JamesWiseman/pen/RRmaBb?ref=ddtomorrow?ref=ddtomorrow.com) functionality:

However, I only wanted three span elements within each button (left, right, background).

Here is the markup for the button:

```
<a href="#" className="btn">Home
  <span className="r"></span>
  <span className="l"></span>
  <span className="background"></span>
</a>
```

and here is the corresponding css:

```
.btn{
  background-color: #FCA311;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 15px;
  width: 100px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

.btn span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
 }

 .btn .l {
   right: 50%;
 }

 .btn .r {
   left: 50%;
 }

 .btn .background {
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
   z-index: -1;
   background-color: #fff;
   opacity: 0;
   transition: all 0.4s ease;
   box-shadow: none;
  }

  .l:hover ~ .background  {
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #fff;
    opacity: 1;
  }

  .r:hover ~ .background {
    box-shadow: -10px 10px 10px #fff;
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

I tried to implement the technique around the '.l' and '.r' span elements to detect hover and adjust the '.background' span's box-shadow accordingly. I do not know what's wrong though. If someone could clarify that would be great.

Comment: Your code works as expected; it correctly applies a partial box shadow based on which half of the square is selected. What is not working the way you would like it to?

Comment: That's weird... it's just not working on my machine i guess. It looked right to me so thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

problem was z-index, you can easily understand by just seeing this code

here i applyed z-index to backgrounder higher and others
and z-index  of left and right is higher then background

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.branding,.navigation{
  margin: 0 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

h1,h2{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul{
  list-style: none;
  height: 30%;
  position: relative;
}

.btn{
  background-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 15px;
  width: 100px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

.btn span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.btn .l {
  right: 50%;
      z-index: 556;
}

.btn .r {
  left: 50%;
      z-index: 556;
}

.btn .background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 555;
  transition: box-shadow 320ms;
}

.l:hover ~ .background  {
  box-shadow: 1px -1px 0 #2c3e50, 2px -2px 0 #2c3e50, 3px -3px 0 #2c3e50, 4px -4px 0 #2c3e50, 5px -5px 0 #2c3e50, 6px -6px 0 #2c3e50, 7px -7px 0 #2c3e50, 8px -8px 0 #2c3e50, 9px -9px 0 #2c3e50, 10px -10px 0 #2c3e50;
}

.r:hover ~ .background {
  box-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #2c3e50, -2px -2px 0 #2c3e50, -3px -3px 0 #2c3e50, -4px -4px 0 #2c3e50, -5px -5px 0 #2c3e50, -6px -6px 0 #2c3e50, -7px -7px 0 #2c3e50, -8px -8px 0 #2c3e50, -9px -9px 0 #2c3e50, -10px -10px 0 #2c3e50;
}


.navigation{
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.branding{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
        <div class='branding'>
          <h1></h1>
          <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
        </div>
        <div class='navigation'>
          <ul>

            <a href="#" class="btn">Home
              <span class="r"></span>
              <span class="l"></span>
              <span class="background"></span>
            </a>

            <a href="#" class="btn">About
              <span class="r"></span>
              <span class="l"></span>
              <span class="background"></span>
            </a>

            <a href="#" class="btn">Contact
              <span class="r"></span>
              <span class="l"></span>
              <span class="background"></span>
            </a>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: While answers are always appreciated, it really helps to provide some additional info regarding **how** your code solves the problem at hand. Doing so aids those with similar (but not identical) problems. Not everyone may be familiar with your exact coding logic, but may understand your general *approach* or *concept*. To help improve your answer, please provide some [**context surrounding it**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762), and see the help article on [**writing great answers**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some tips on how to make your answers count :)

Comment: yes right,i should add more detail about what i did in my code.., my English skill is is not good but i will try my best to explain.. thanx for pointing to that tips

Comment: I went line by line and compared your example to mine and it's pretty much exactly the same. I still have no idea it's not working. I will make a codepen and see if it works

Comment: update: i even added onClick listeners to console.log if the spans were listening and they were... idk what else to do at this point

Comment: hope this solution meet your requirement